# Select rows 2 days old except weekend

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having an issue retrieving some transactions from my table, the idea is i wanna delete all transaction the users made since 2 days but i wanna exclude the weekends from counts (weekend here is Friday and Saturday), so far i can get the 2 days old records but no weekend exclude

```
SELECT c1
FROM my_table
WHERE TRANS_DATE <= (TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 3)..
```

Example: a user made his request on Tuesday i have to delete the request on Thursday,, but if he made it on Thursday i have to delete it on Monday..

any ideas? 
thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try determining the day of the week with a case expression and subtracting accordingly, for example:

```
SELECT c1
FROM my_table
WHERE 
TRANS_DATE <= (
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' ) = 'Monday' then TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 5
     ELSE TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 3 END
);
```

Comment: Note, for some territories the week begins also on Saturday = 1 or even on Thursday (as far as I remember). Better use `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' ) = 'Monday'`, because `Day` also depends on current session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but how i can alter my current session am sorry am not a DBA.. can you help me with this? am using oracle 12c as DB and 11g as developer

Comment: that is the very good suggestion from @WernfriedDomscheit; by using TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' ) = 'Monday' you don't need to worry about the particular NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE you are under. I've updated the SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update, so that will consider Monday as a first day of the week? actually i need Sunday as a first day of the week

Comment: yes, you can replace 'Monday' with 'Sunday' and it will evaluate true on Sundays

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c1
FROM my_table
WHERE TRANS_DATE >= sysdate - decode(to_number(to_char(sysdate -1,'D')), 1,4, 6,3, 7,4, 2)
```

First day is Sunday
If previous day is Sunday or Saturday then we have two days off
If previous day is Friday then we have one day off
plus two days

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for jumping in to answer a question. Two suggestions: please format your source code by indenting it four spaces, and please give a few words of explanation of why your answer works. I'll fix the formatting; you should edit your post to offer the explanation.

Comment: Be aware, result of `to_char(sysdate -1,'D')` depends on the current sessions `NLS_TERRITORY` settings.